# Solr Search focus the exact match when open the document

Tags: solr4

I want that when we click on search result link for searched keyword,it should open the docuement(pdf) with focus on first appearence of searched keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for [Solr Highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters)